# The menu anchor bar is not functioning properly(fullpage.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

Consider the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/styles/style.css" />">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/styles/jquery.fullPage.css" />">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.easings.min.js" />" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery.fullPage.js" />" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(' #fullpage ').fullpage({
             sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE'],
             anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', 'thirdPage'],
             menu: ' #mymenu ',
             css3: true
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>


<ul id="mymenu">
<li data-menuanchor="firstPage"><a href="#firstPage">Health Metrics</a></li>
<li data-menuanchor="secondPage"><a href="#secondPage">Client Login Information</a></li>
<li data-menuanchor="thirdPage"><a href="#thirdPage">Active Operator Information</a>     </li>

</ul>

<div id="fullpage">


<div class="section">
 ## Stuffs
</div>



<div class="section">
 ## Stuffs
</div>

 <div class="section">
 ## Stuffs
</div>


</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">


setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 20000); 
</script>



</html>
```

The Anchor tab is not fixed at the top and does not display as button. When it goes to the second page it vanishes. But in the demo it displays as nice button and stays at the top.

The demo page : [Click Here](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's basic CSS. Nothing to do with the plugin itself.
You have to use a fixed position for it...

If you want to apply it exactly as in the fullPage.js demo, then:

```
#mymenu{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 70;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```